# How to reduce an array of ranges to a minimal set of ranges using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, range

I have an array of alphanumeric postal codes that could look something like this:

```
PostalCodes(0) = "AA000-DD130"
PostalCodes(1) = "DD131-DD150"
PostalCodes(2) = "DD151-EE180"
PostalCodes(3) = "EE300-EE600"
PostalCodes(4) = "EE450-EE700"
PostalCodes(5) = "EE800"
PostalCodes(6) = "EE810"
PostalCodes(7) = "EE811"
PostalCodes(8) = "EE812"
PostalCodes(9) = "EE813"
PostalCodes(10) = "EE814"
PostalCodes(11) = "EE815"
```

And I want it to optimize to something like this:

```
PostalCodes(0) = "AA000-EE180"
PostalCodes(1) = "EE300-EE700"
PostalCodes(2) = "EE800"
PostalCodes(3) = "EE810-EE815"
```

As you can see ranges can overlap or there might be gaps, its ok, I only want to optimize(reduce) the postal codes as much as I can.
I already have a code using For loops but I would like to know if there is a way to use Linq to do this task faster and improve performance?

I'm using vb.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how would you use such a thing?  `"AB107-AB130"` is not a range, but a string containing two bits of data.  Better to store a collection of object such as a `Range` made of a Start and End values.  Internally it could parse the data to store a prefix and high, low values.

Comment: Do your postal codes always begin with "AB"?

Comment: `I already have a code using For loops but I would like to know if there is a way to use Linq to do this task faster and improve performance`, `LINQ` may not be any faster, it just extends query capabilities to the language syntax of C# and Visual Basic. In general it just introduces standard, easily-learned patterns for querying alternative to the long approaches we commonly see. We cant provide input to help you as you havent posted what you are using. More than likely your code could be optimized but without seeing it, it is useless at this point.

Comment: The postal codes could be numeric or alphanumeric, it depends on the country, we work with many countries.

Comment: @Melipao How are you supposed to know if ranges should be combined in that case? Will the alphanumeric prefix always be two characters?

Comment: Updated my answer to handle your new data.

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much does it:

```
Dim PostalCodes(11) As String
PostalCodes(0) = "AA000-DD130"
PostalCodes(1) = "DD131-DD150"
PostalCodes(2) = "DD151-EE180"
PostalCodes(3) = "EE300-EE600"
PostalCodes(4) = "EE450-EE700"
PostalCodes(5) = "EE800"
PostalCodes(6) = "EE810"
PostalCodes(7) = "EE811"
PostalCodes(8) = "EE812"
PostalCodes(9) = "EE813"
PostalCodes(10) = "EE814"
PostalCodes(11) = "EE815"

Dim splits = _ 
    PostalCodes _
        .Select(Function (x) If(x.Contains("-"), x.Split("-"c), { x, x })) _
        .Select(Function (ps) ps.Select(Function (p) New With _
        { _
            .Prefix = p.Substring(0, 2), _
            .Value = Integer.Parse(p.Substring(2)) _
        }).ToArray()) _
        .ToArray()

Dim results = _
    splits _
        .Skip(1) _
        .Aggregate( _
            splits.Take(1).ToList(), _
            Function (a, x)
                Dim l = a.Last()
                If x(0).Prefix = l(1).Prefix AndAlso x(0).Value <= l(1).Value + 1 Then
                    a.RemoveAt(a.Count - 1)
                    a.Add( _
                    { _
                        New With _
                        { _
                            .Prefix = l(0).Prefix, _
                            .Value = l(0).Value _
                        }, _
                        New With _
                        { _
                            .Prefix = l(1).Prefix, _
                            .Value = x(1).Value _
                        } _                     
                    })
                Else
                    a.Add(x)
                End If
                Return a
            End Function) _
        .Select(Function (xs) String.Format("{0}{1:000}-{2}{3:000}", xs(0).Prefix, xs(0).Value, xs(1).Prefix, xs(1).Value)) _
        .ToArray()
```

It gives:

```
AA000-DD180 
EE300-EE700 
EE800-EE800 
EE810-EE815
```

A small bit of work remaining to get rid of the double `"EE800-EE800"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method to convert ranges into tuples with StartPrefix, Start, EndPrefix, End values:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function RangeToTuple(ByVal strRange As String) As (StartPrefix As String, Start As Integer, EndPrefix As String, [End] As Integer
    If strRange.Contains("-") Then
        Dim twoRanges = strRange.Split("-")
        Dim intRanges = twoRanges.Select(Function(rs) rs.Substring(2).ToInteger()).ToList()
        Return (twoRanges(0).Substring(0, 2), intRanges(0), twoRanges(1).Substring(0, 2), intRanges(1))
    Else
        Dim intRange = strRange.Substring(2).ToInteger()
        Return (strRange.Substring(0, 2), intRange, strRange.Substring(0, 2), intRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Which uses a simple extension for converting String to Integer:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToInteger(s As String) As Integer
    Return Convert.ToInt32(s)
End Function
```

Using a custom extension method that is a variation of the APL scan operator that works like `Aggregate` but returns the intermediate values, and uses a `ValueTuple` to return the original values with the intermediate calculations:

```
<Extension()>
Public Iterator Function ScanPair(Of T, TKey)(src As IEnumerable(Of T), seedKey As TKey, combine As Func(Of (Key As TKey, Value As T), T, TKey)) As IEnumerable(Of (Key As TKey, Value As T))
    Using srce = src.GetEnumerator()
        If srce.MoveNext() Then
            Dim prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current)

            While srce.MoveNext()
                Yield prevkv
                prevkv = (combine(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current)
            End While
            Yield prevkv
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

And an extension method that groups based on a predicate:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GroupByWhile(Of T, TRes)(src As IEnumerable(Of T), test As Func(Of T, T, Boolean), result As Func(Of T, TRes)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, TRes))
    Return src.ScanPair(1, Function(kvp, cur) If(test(kvp.Value, cur), kvp.Key, kvp.Key + 1)) _
              .GroupBy(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) result(kvp.Value))
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function GroupByWhile(Of T)(src As IEnumerable(Of T), test As Func(Of T, T, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, T))
    Return src.GroupByWhile(test, Function(e) e)
End Function
```

Then you can use LINQ to process the tuples:

```
Dim combinedRanges = input.Select(Function(rs) rs.RangeToTuple()) _
                          .GroupByWhile(Function(prev, cur) prev.EndPrefix = cur.StartPrefix And cur.Start <= prev.End+1 And prev.End <= cur.End) _
                          .Select(Function(kvpg) (kvpg.First().StartPrefix, kvpg.First().Start, kvpg.Last().EndPrefix, kvpg.Last().End)) _
                          .Select(Function(tp) If(tp.Start = tp.End, $"{tp.StartPrefix}{tp.Start}", _
                                                                     $"{tp.StartPrefix}{tp.Start}-{tp.EndPrefix}{tp.End}"))
```

NOTE: After writing this answer, I realized I could generalize my sequence grouping constructs to group on a predicate, and make it more accessible.

Converted to VB per comment.

Comment: You should also post the answer in VB.NET

Comment: @djv Converted to VB, thought it was painful.